# Binomial Problem : Find the coefficient of this equation!

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to find $x^{13}$ from this equation:

$\left ( x^{3}+1 \right )^{2}\left ( x^{2}-\frac{2}{x} \right )^{8}$

I'm very confused with these equation and don't know how to solve using Binomial Newton Theorem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Your expression can be rewritten as
$$\left ( x^{6}+2x^3+1 \right )\left ( x^{2}-\frac{2}{x} \right )^{8}$$
Now you can manually find and add required coefficients
$$x^{13}=x^{6}\times x^{7}=x^{3}\times x^{10}=x^{0}\times x^{13}$$
Your answer will be then

> Coeficient of $x^7$ in $\left ( x^{2}-\frac{2}{x} \right )^{8}$+$2\times$Coeficient of $x^{10}$ in $\left ( x^{2}-\frac{2}{x} \right )^{8}$+Coeficient of $x^{13}$ in $\left ( x^{2}-\frac{2}{x} \right )^{8}$ $$=-448+2\times112-16=-240$$

Comment: my teacher method is like yours... but i still confused with nthat...

Comment: yes, but i'm confused with multiplication equation..... if only like (x+y)^n, i can do it but if (x+y)^n * (a+b)^m, i become confused....

Comment: why x^13 only come from = x^6 * x^7, x^3 * x^10, and x^0 * x^13. Could be x^8*x^5 or others...

Comment: yep... I still trying to do it...

Comment: Why we must find the power of 8 only, and doesn't use to find another power?

Comment: I will mark your answer as default answer, but please explain why we must count on power of 8 only?

Comment: 2xcoefficient of x^3 because there is a constant 2 inside the power of 2 equation ya?

Comment: @user3658777 Well don't expand it yourself see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%28x%5E2-%282%29%2F%28x%29%29%5E8) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%28x%5E3%2B1%29%5E2%28x%5E2-%282%29%2F%28x%29%29%5E8)

Answer (score 3):

You could start with $\left ( x^{3}+1 \right )^{2}\left ( x^{2}-\frac{2}{x} \right )^{8} = \frac{1}{x^8} \left ( x^{3}+1 \right )^{2}\left ( x^{3}-2 \right )^{8}$  so your question is equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in $\left ( x^{3}+1 \right )^{2}\left ( x^{3}-2 \right )^{8}$.

Letting $y=x^3$, this is the same as finding the coefficient of $y^7$ in  $\left ( y+1 \right )^{2}\left ( y-2 \right )^{8}$.

This requires some calculating, but when expanding $\left( y-2 \right )^{8}$ you can ignore any powers smaller than $y^5$.

Comment: Thanks for your method.....

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the excellent answers provided earlier by others, here's a table which might be helpful. The table shows that powers of $x$ from the expansion of the first and second terms are $6, 3, 0$, and $16, 13, 10,...,-8$ respectively. The power 13 is a resultant of the product of powers $(6,3,0)$ with $(7,10,13)$ respectively, and its coefficient is the sum of coefficients of the corresponding products, as shown in the highlighted area.

[image]